# How to throw an exception within a method?

Tags: scala

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = if(xs.isEmpty) throw java.util.NoSuchElementException else ...
```

If `xs` is empty, an exception should be thrown. However I get an error, since `java.util.NoSuchElementException` does not match the return type `Int`

Comment: This is not a typing issue (read the error message carefully). You can return `throw` from any function because it returns `Nothing` which is a subset of every type.

Comment: Use `throw new`, not just `throw`. NoSuchElementException is a class and needs to be instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try

```
throw new NoSuchElementException("empty list")
```

You're trying to throw a class. In Scala, just like in Java, you can only throw an instance of a class and not the class itself. You'd have to use one of NoSuchElementException's constructors.

Comment: I would add a word about how it's not really Scala like and show how you would go at returning `Try`.